# Bluetooth Pairing Without users' confirmation

Tags: android, bluetooth, pairing

Can I pair smartphone over Bluetooth without a need to confirm this in user interface, accept to pair this devices. I use android studio. I don't need to exchange data over them, I need just pairing without any action. And then safely pair with smartphone over Bluetooth without any user's action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no, but you shouldn't anyway.

The only way to do this in Android is by using the [BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#L1513) permission, which, as you can see, is only granted to apps in `/system/priv-app/` or apps signed by the platform key of the device.

So unless you have root and can move your app to `/system/priv-app/`, you can't do what you want. Even if you *can* do this, however, don't. It's not a good user experience when someone installs an app, only for it to move itself to the system partition and start pairing without any notification.

Comment: `BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED` had been deprecated; `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` is left.

Comment: @MartinZeitler and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN doesn't let you pair without user confirmation.

Comment: ...one can send pairing requests from a remote device - while this still would cause a confirmation dialog to pop up.

Comment: @MartinZeitler also, I'm not sure where you see that it's deprecated. The link I provided doesn't have anything mentioning that, and the framework still uses the permission.

Comment: @MartinZeitler but that's not the OP's question: `without a need to confirm this in user interface`

Comment: try adding it to a `Manifest.xml` and you will see it with yellow background... the question might be pointless in general, simply because it ignores security features.

Comment: It's a system API. Android Studio is going to warn you about that.

Comment: `BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED` was available previously, but meanwhile not for apps with later API levels anymore, despite still being used by the ART... even without documentation I'm pretty sure, due to refactoring that.

Comment: `BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED` is still used in the framework, mainly in [BluetoothAdapter](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/c1fd61b3026e15c652ecfd77e7962c2a656f9023/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.java) @MartinZeitler

Comment: My links are from the `master` branch of AOSP. It's very much still in the later APIs.

Comment: [System UI still uses it](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/SystemUI/AndroidManifest.xml#L57). It's not available to third party applications, like I just said in my answerr, but it exists and can be used by apps in `priv-app` or by apps signed by the platform key.